# Phrase for a process ignoring individual members' needs

Tags: phrase-request

I need a phrase for a process which goes on large scale, trying to optimize overall output while ignoring needs of individual members.

The focus should be on the negative aspect: ignoring the needs.

(e.g. a doctor suggesting the same cure for everybody, being helpful for 80% of his customers, but not at all for the others).

Comment: Pondering this.  "Impersonal" is the generic term, but we might also say something like "industrial" or "factory farm medicine" or treating patients like "production line".  Basically, manufacturing-related metaphors.

Comment: Is it something like *universalize*?

Comment: @DamkerngT. He's looking for a pejorative, but I don't think we have one with this exact meaning. "Production line" is close, but only when applied to things outside of manufacturing. _**One size fits all**_ is the closest I can come.

Comment: Thanks for all! Yes,  to be pejorative is important.  So far @Andrew's  "production line" is the closest to the meaning I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Some phrases which comes to mind are

> for the greater good
>   on the whole
>   on average

which presumes the whole over the individual.